# Maximal Number of Functional Dependencies (including trivial)

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

In a relationship R of N attributes how many functional dependencies are there (including trivial)?

I know that trivial dependencies are those where the right hand side is a subset of the left hand side but I'm not sure how to calculate the upper bound on the dependencies.

Any information regarding the answer and the approach to it would be greatly appreciated.

  -

Comment: A functional dependency states that some attributes determine others. Normally by "the FDs of (or in) a relation value (or variable)" we mean the ones that hold, ie are true statements. Here your question should probably really be, what are all the FDs that can be expressed using the given attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum possible number of functional dependencies is

- the number of possible left-hand sides * the number of possible right-hand sides

We're including trivial functional dependencies, so the number of possible left-hand sides equals the number of possible right-hand sides. So this simplifies to

- (the number of possible left-hand sides)<sup>2</sup>

Let's say you have R{∅AB}. There are three attributes.<sup>1</sup> The number of possible left-hand sides is

- combinations of 3 attributes taken 1 at a time, plus
- combinations of 3 attributes taken 2 at a time, plus
- combinations of 3 attributes taken 3 at a time

which equals `3+3+1`, or 7. So there are at most 7<sup>2</sup> possible functional dependencies for any R having three attributes: 49. The order of attributes doesn't matter, so we use formulas for combinations, not for permutations.

If you start with R{∅ABC}, you have

- combinations of 4 attributes taken 1 at a time, plus
- combinations of 4 attributes taken 2 at a time, plus
- combinations of 4 attributes taken 3 at a time, plus
- combinations of 4 attributes taken 4 at a time

which equals `4+6+4+1`, or 15. So there are at most 15<sup>2</sup> possible functional dependencies for any R having four attributes: 225.

Once you know this formula, these calculations are simple using a spreadsheet. It's also pretty easy to write a program to generate every possible functional dependency using a scripting language like Ruby or Python.

[The Wikipedia article on combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Example_of_counting_combinations) has examples of how to count the combinations, with and without using factorials.

All possible combinations from R{∅AB}:

```
A->A A->B A->∅ A->AB A->A∅ A->B∅ A->AB∅ 
B->A B->B B->∅ B->AB B->A∅ B->B∅ B->AB∅ 
∅->A ∅->B ∅->∅ ∅->AB ∅->A∅ ∅->B∅ ∅->AB∅ 
AB->A AB->B AB->∅ AB->AB AB->A∅ AB->B∅ AB->AB∅ 
A∅->A A∅->B A∅->∅ A∅->AB A∅->A∅ A∅->B∅ A∅->AB∅ 
B∅->A B∅->B B∅->∅ B∅->AB B∅->A∅ B∅->B∅ B∅->AB∅ 
AB∅->A AB∅->B AB∅->∅ AB∅->AB AB∅->A∅ AB∅->B∅ AB∅->AB∅
```

---

1. Most people ignore the empty set. They'd say R{∅AB} has only two attributes, A and B, and they'd write it as R{AB}.

Comment: The empty set can be the determinant of a FD (and can be a candidate key).

Comment: Off-by-one error. Except in the context of *this* question, I'm off by more than one. (All FDs in the form ATTR->{} are trivial. We also need all FDs in the form {}->ATTR.)

Comment: The general form is any subset determining any subset. So your anwswer also needs 0 at a time. Which means adding not just singleton & {} but all possible subsets & {}, including {}->{}.

Comment: I understand how you got 3 + 3 + 1 using combinations, but how do you take into account the empty set? Is there a generalized form for calculating this?